# Regex string reducer in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, .net-4.5

Say I have this unknown string :

```
var t = "G9906QZN-SXK9-TUCE-10F5-CB2C1DA9D24A.hello";
```

I need to generate a regex for that string in a general way.

Please notice , not a regex for the *exact* string , otherwise I would've used the exact chars.

In other words : all those 3 should have the same regex :

```
G9906QZN-SXK9-TUCE-10F5-CB2C1DA9D24A.hello
G9906QZN-SXK9-TUCE-267F-F361D103A627.hello
G9906QZN-SXK9-TUCE-0360-370482E00155.hello
```

And all those 3 should also have the same regex :

```
G9906QZN^SXK9^TUCE^10F5^CB2C1DA9D24A.hello
G9906QZN^SXK9^TUCE^267F^F361D103A627.hello
G9906QZN^SXK9^TUCE^0360^370482E00155.hello
```

Also  - there can be more than one splitter - **it's a random pattern generated files** :

So all those 3 should also have the same regex :

```
G9906QZN^SXK9 TUCE[10F5-CB2C1DA9D24A.hello
G9906QZN^SXK9 TUCE[267F-F361D103A627.hello
G9906QZN^SXK9 TUCE[0360-370482E00155.hello
```

So this is what I've done : (*ignore case sensitive for now*)

**Code:**

```
var t = "G9906QZN-SXK9-TUCE-10F5-CB2C1DA9D24A.hello";

    List<string> lst = new List<string>(); //stringBuilder can also be used.

    foreach (char element in t)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(element) || char.IsLetter(element)) 
          lst.Add(@"\w");
        else  
          lst.Add(@"\"+element); //escape all other

    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join( "",lst.ToArray())  );
```

**Result:**

```
\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\-\w\w\w\w\-\w\w\w\w\-\w\w\w\w\-\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\.\w\w\w\w\w
```

**Question:**

I want to "shrink" that regex into something like :

```
\w{8}\-\w{4}\-\w{4}\-\w{12}\.\w{5}
```

*Before* I start doing something very ugly like : first occurrence , last occurrence , and reset counters , Is there any more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: Why not use string split method on the dash and period? : t.Split(new char {'-','.'});

Comment: @jdweng `-` is not guaranteed to be the splitter tomorrow the string  can be : `G9906QZN^SXK9^TUCE^10F5^CB2C1DA9D24A.hello`

Comment: in that case you can use **[`\w{8}(?:\W\w{4}){3}\W\w{12}\.\w{5}`](https://regex101.com/r/xD4cA4/2)**

Comment: @kostbone No it's nt a guid. it's a random pattern generated files.

Comment: will the splitter be same throughout the string or can it be `G9906QZN^SXK9-TUCE*10F5^CB2C1DA9D24A.hello`?

Comment: @rock321987 All I want is an elegent way for inserting the counters. No need for non-captured groups etc.

Comment: @rock321987 no. I'll write it also.

Comment: @rock321987 Again , I have succeeded to generate the regex, I jsut want to shrink that regex.

Comment: @rock321987 it's a simple string manipulation to go from this : `\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\-\w\w\w\w\-\w\w\w\w\-\w\w\w\w\-\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\.\w\w\w\w\w` into  : `\w{8}\-\w{4}\-\w{4}\-\w{12}\.\w{5}`. simple loops and counters and remembering first and last occurence. that's all. Alli'm after is to count those middle repeated  strings and insert them like in my question.

Comment: The add the '^' char to the array of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use regex to generate it

```
var t = "G9906QZN-SXK9-TUCE-10F5-CB2C1DA9D24A.hello";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Regex.Escape(t), @"\w+", m => @"\w{" + m.Length + "}"));
```

result:

```
\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}\.\w{5}
```

If you want to treat `_` as a separator, then you should use `[\w-[_]]` instead of simple `\w`

```
Regex.Replace(Regex.Escape(t),
    @"[\w-[_]]+", m => $@"[\w-[_]]{{{m.Length}}}");
```

Comment: if `_` (underscore) is meant to be a separator too `\w` won't fit and you have to replace it by `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (or just `[a-z0-9]` and ignore case). Also why a replace for escaping you match \W but all characters in \w won't be escaped anyway so just use `Regex.Escape(t)` no ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht: you are right about escaping. If you replace `\w` with anything else, that means that you cannot have `\w` as the output expression so this also needs to be fixed in that case

Comment: That's what I was about to add ^^ anyway unless I'm mistaken `Regex.Replace (Regex.Escape (t), "[a-zA-Z0-9]+", m => $"[a-zA-Z0-9]{{{m.Length}}}");` should do the job

Comment: @Sehnsucht what about `_` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Sehnsucht's solution will work for `_` but the output query is rather ugly ;)

Comment: @RoyiNamir try it ;-) it should considered as a separator. but as said by myself and @Adassko if you keep \w in the generated regex it will match `_` there too hence the use of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` in both case in my preceding comment despite it's "ugliness" (^^) it'll do the job

Comment: Yeah https://i.imgur.com/XVpOlre.png . I don't care about the pattern since a human is not reading it. Tnx

Comment: Final  : `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Regex.Escape(t), @"[a-z0-9]+", m => @"[a-z0-9]{" + m.Length + "}",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));` ----> `[a-z0-9]{8}\^[a-z0-9]{4}_[a-z0-9]{4}\[[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12}\.[a-z0-9]{5}`

Comment: @RoyiNamir you also need to note that `\w` is not only a-zA-Z0-9 but also special characters like `ą` and `Ü` for example. If you need to keep those characters in mind then you need query like this: `Regex.Replace(Regex.Escape (t), @"((?!_)\w)+", m => $@"(?:[^_]{{{m.Length}}})\w{{{m.Length}}}")`

Comment: @Adassko , it doesn't work when i try to match that regex : https://dotnetfiddle.net/LdeKjZ

Comment: @RoyiNamir: yes, I made a little mistake, there should be `=` instead of `:`. It's in the correct version in the answer but I cannot edit my comment anymore

Comment: Instead of the ugly lookahead you could also use `[^\W_]`

Comment: thanks @SebastianProske :) I didn't know about second syntax and haven't thought about the first one; updated my answer

Comment: @SebastianProske What is that syntax `[\w-[_]]+` js's regex doesn't seems to accept it. .net - does. can you explain this ? (I know what [...] is)

Comment: Why does .net regex do accept non-english chars as \w while js's doesn't ?  https://i.imgur.com/gPxh3By.png

Comment: @RoyiNamir It is called character class subtraction. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_13). It is a special feature of .net-regex. [JS-regex is much less powerful.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)